# nullPointerException when using Aysnctask, android

Tags: android, weather-api, openweathermap

I am writing an android application to get the current weather using latitude , longitude using openWeatherMap API. I used Aysnctask to get the weather, but the application crashes and it gives me a nullPointerException.

here the aysnctask:

```
private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

        @Override
        protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {

            Weather weather = new Weather();
        //  String data = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

            String data = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0],params[1]));
            try {
                weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

                // Let's retrieve the icon
                weather.iconData = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getImage(weather.currentCondition.getIcon()));

            } catch (JSONException e) {             
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return weather;

    }





    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {         
            super.onPostExecute(weather);

            if (weather.iconData != null && weather.iconData.length > 0) {
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(weather.iconData, 0, weather.iconData.length); 
                imgView.setImageBitmap(img);
            }


            condDescr.setText(weather.currentCondition.getCondition() + "(" + weather.currentCondition.getDescr() + ")");
            temp.setText("" + Math.round((weather.temperature.getTemp() - 275.15)) + "°C");
            hum.setText("" + weather.currentCondition.getHumidity() + "%");
            press.setText("" + weather.currentCondition.getPressure() + " hPa");
            windSpeed.setText("" + weather.wind.getSpeed() + " mps");
            windDeg.setText("" + weather.wind.getDeg() + "°");

        }

 }
```

the parameters of doInBackground method should be current latitude, longitude. I call the aysnktask like this:

```
JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{currentLatitude,currentLongitude});
```

and I make the connection to openWeatherMap like this:

```
public String getWeatherData(String lat,String lng) {
        HttpURLConnection con = null ;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            con=(HttpURLConnection)(new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%"+Double.parseDouble(lat)+"&lon="+Double.parseDouble(lng))).openConnection();   

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.connect();

            // Let's read the response
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = null;
            while (  (line = br.readLine()) != null )
                buffer.append(line + "\r\n");

            is.close();
            con.disconnect();
            return buffer.toString();
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try { is.close(); } catch(Throwable t) {}
            try { con.disconnect(); } catch(Throwable t) {}
        }

        return null;

    }
```

the nullPointerException is at this line :

```
weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);
```

here is the logCat:

```
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp.JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(JSONWeatherParser.java:42)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp.MainActivity$JSONWeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:290)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp.MainActivity$JSONWeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-03 11:34:29.110: E/AndroidRuntime(16271):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

this is getWeather method :

```
public static Weather getWeather(String data) throws JSONException  {
        Weather weather = new Weather();

        // We create out JSONObject from the data
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);

        // We start extracting the info
        Location1 loc = new Location1();

        JSONObject coordObj = getObject("coord", jObj);
        loc.setLatitude(getFloat("lat", coordObj));
        loc.setLongitude(getFloat("lon", coordObj));

        JSONObject sysObj = getObject("sys", jObj);
        loc.setCountry(getString("country", sysObj));
        loc.setSunrise(getInt("sunrise", sysObj));
        loc.setSunset(getInt("sunset", sysObj));
        loc.setCity(getString("name", jObj));
        weather.location = loc;

        // We get weather info (This is an array)
        JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("weather");

        // We use only the first value
        JSONObject JSONWeather = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
        weather.currentCondition.setWeatherId(getInt("id", JSONWeather));
        weather.currentCondition.setDescr(getString("description", JSONWeather));
        weather.currentCondition.setCondition(getString("main", JSONWeather));
        weather.currentCondition.setIcon(getString("icon", JSONWeather));

        JSONObject mainObj = getObject("main", jObj);
        weather.currentCondition.setHumidity(getInt("humidity", mainObj));
        weather.currentCondition.setPressure(getInt("pressure", mainObj));
        weather.temperature.setMaxTemp(getFloat("temp_max", mainObj));
        weather.temperature.setMinTemp(getFloat("temp_min", mainObj));
        weather.temperature.setTemp(getFloat("temp", mainObj));

        // Wind
        JSONObject wObj = getObject("wind", jObj);
        weather.wind.setSpeed(getFloat("speed", wObj));
        weather.wind.setDeg(getFloat("deg", wObj));

        // Clouds
        JSONObject cObj = getObject("clouds", jObj);
        weather.clouds.setPerc(getInt("all", cObj));

        // We download the icon to show


        return weather;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: `getWeather` returns null.

Comment: look at the logcat and tell us what line, the NPE is on and we can help

Comment: return buffer.toString(); is probably never called. Can you check if catch(Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace();} is entered in your getWeatherData method ?

Comment: Print out the value of your data variable to see what you are passing to the static getWeather method

Comment: Can you please let us know line number 42.

Comment: seems your getWeatherData(String,String) returning null. and thus **data** is null...

Comment: @Mike it crashes without printing the value of data

Comment: @SiddharthVyas this is line 42: 'JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);'

Comment: Means the data you are sending is null.You can check like if(data==null){ // Do some stuff } else {//Do some stuff}

Comment: @roa.tah: please share string which you are getting in `data` from server before calling getWeather method

Comment: could you post your `getWeather()` method?

Comment: @SiddharthVyas nothing is printed in both cases.

Comment: @grexter89 ok, I will .

Comment: @SiddharthVyas I think there is something wrong in my aysnctask.

Comment: can you also mark line 42 in `getWeather()`?

Comment: @grexter89 this is line 42: 'JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);

Comment: have you logged what `data` contains? i guess it's not a valid JSON-object

Comment: @grexter89 no, I am sure it is valid. I tried my application using current city name and it worked, but I modified it to take latitude and magnitude and it doesn't work any more~!!